# Lumen Access Models from Kernel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, lumen

I have a fresh install of Lumen 7.

> Lumen (7.0.2) (Laravel Components ^7.0)

I have an issue when I try to use a model inside the schedule function of the Kernel.php.

```
In Model.php line 1283:

Call to a member function connection() on null
```

**Kernel.php**

```php
<?php

namespace App\Console;

use App\Flight;
use Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule;
use Laravel\Lumen\Console\Kernel as ConsoleKernel;

class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel
{
    /**
     * The Artisan commands provided by your application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $commands = [
        //
    ];

    /**
     * Define the application's command schedule.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule  $schedule
     * @return void
     */
    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        Flight::all();
    }
}
```

I touched noting into the model, it's the file generated from the artisan command `make:model`.

Of course, I have uncommented withEloquent in the app.php

```php
$app->withFacades();
$app->withEloquent();
```

I know that it's working fine since the same line of code works in a route callback.

I event tried with Laravel 7 : its working.
and Lumen 6.3.4 : not working.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I've been having a similar problem but the only work around I've been able to come up with is replacing

```php
Flight::all();
```

With

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

$flights = DB::table('flights')->get();
```

It's not the best but until Lumen gets around to allowing eloquent in the Kernel it'll do for now.